# .NET package restore in Docker cached separately from build

Tags: docker, .net-core, nuget-package-restore

**How does one build a Docker image of a .NET 5/C# app so that the restored NuGet packages are cached properly?** By proper caching I mean that when sources (but not project files) are changed, the layer containing restored packages is still taken from cache during `docker build`.

It is a best practice in Docker to perform package restore before adding the full sources and building the app itself as it makes it possible to cache the restore separately, which significantly speeds up the builds. I know that not only the `packages` directory, but also the `bin` and `obj` directories of individual projects have to be preserved from `dotnet restore` to `dotnet publish --no-restore` so that everything works together. I also know that once the cache is busted, all following layers are built anew.

My issue is that I cannot come up with a way to COPY just the `*.csproj`. If I copy more than just the `*.csproj`, source changes bust the cache. I could copy them into one place outside the `docker build` and simply COPY them inside the build, but I want to be able to **build the image even outside the pipeline**, manually, with a reasonably simple command. (Is it an unreasonable requirement?)

For the web app that consists of multiple projects in a pretty standard folder structure `src/*/*.csproj`, I came up with this attempt that tries to compensate for too many files being copied into the image (which still busts the cache):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /src
COPY NuGet.Config NuGet.Config
COPY src/ src/
RUN find . -name NuGet.Config -prune -o \! -type d \! -name \*.csproj -exec rm -f '{}' + \
    && find -depth -type d -empty -exec rmdir '{}' \;
RUN dotnet restore src/Company.Product.Component.App/Company.Product.Component.App.csproj
COPY src/ src/
RUN dotnet publish src/Company.Product.Component.App/Company.Product.Component.App.csproj -c Release --no-restore -o /out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS run-env
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Company.Product.Component.App.dll"]
```

I also tried splitting the build-env stage into two just after the restore, copying the /root/.nuget/packages and /src to the build stage, but that did not help either.

The first RUN line and the one immediately before should be replaced with something that copies just the `*.csproj`, but I don't know what that is. The **obvious laborious solution** is to have a separate COPY line for each `*.csproj`, but that does not feel right as projects tend to be added and removed so it makes the Dockerfile hard to maintain. I have tried `COPY src/*/*.csproj src/` and then fixing the flattened paths, which is a trick that I googled, but it did not work for me as my Docker processes the wildcards just in file names and interprets directory names literally, emitting an error for nonexistent `src/*` directory. I am using **Docker Desktop 3.5.2 (66501)**, which uses the BuildKit backend to build the images, but I am open to changing the tooling if it helps.

This leaves me clueless about how to satisfy the relatively simple set of my requirements. My options seem exhausted. **Have I missed something? Do I have to accept a tradeoff and drop some of my requirements?**

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51373386/2309376) regarding the csproj files? Ignore the first solution (it uses compression) but I have used the second and third solutions successfully.

Comment: Also you might want to remove the first `COPY src/ src/` on line 4 as that looks like it is copying everything before you try to just copy the `.csproj` files

Comment: @SimplyGed, yes, I've read that answer. That's where the `COPY src/*/*.csproj src/` in my last but one paragraph come from. Guessing from the answer's date, it did not run using BuildKit those days. Think I tried building even with DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 and ran into other issues, but I will try again and add the results here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The lack of support for wildcards in directory names is likely a **missing feature in BuildKit**. The issue has already been reported at [moby/buildkit GitHub as #1900](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/1900).

Till the issue is fixed, [**disable BuildKit**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66839653/2157640) if you don't need any of its features. Either

1. set the environment variable DOCKER_BUILDKIT to zero (`0`), or
2. edit the Docker daemon config so that the "buildkit" feature is set to false and restart the daemon.

In Docker Desktop, the config is easily accessible in Settings > Docker Engine. This method of turning off the feature is recommended by the [Docker Desktop 3.2.0 release notes](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/#docker-desktop-320) where BuildKit was first enabled by default.

Once BuildKit is disabled, **replace**

```
COPY src/ src/
RUN find . -name NuGet.Config -prune -o \! -type d \! -name \*.csproj -exec rm -f '{}' + \
    && find -depth -type d -empty -exec rmdir '{}' \;
```

with

```
COPY src/*/*.csproj src/
RUN for from in src/*.csproj; do to=$(echo "$from" | sed 's/\/\([^/]*\)\.csproj$/\/\1&/') \
    && mkdir -p "$(dirname "$to")" && mv "$from" "$to"; done
```

The COPY will succeed without busting the cache and the RUN will fix the paths. It relies on the fact the projects are in the "src" directory, each in a separate directory of the same name as the project file.

This is basically the solution at the bottom of [VonC's answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51373386/2157640). The answer also mentions [Moby issue #15858](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15858), which has an interesting discussion on the topic.

There is a [dotnet tool for the paths fixup](https://github.com/benmccallum/dotnet-references/blob/master/docs/Dockerfile-use-case.md), too, but I have not tested it.

An **alternate solution that does not require disabling BuildKit** is to [split the original stage in two](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15858#issuecomment-614157331) right after cleaning up the copied files, i.e. just before restore (not after!).

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS projects-env
WORKDIR /src
COPY NuGet.Config NuGet.Config
COPY src/ src/
RUN find . -name NuGet.Config -prune -o \! -type d \! -name \*.csproj -exec rm -f '{}' + \
    && find . -depth -type d -empty -exec rmdir '{}' \;

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /src
COPY --from=projects-env /src /src
RUN dotnet restore src/Company.Product.Component.App/Company.Product.Component.App.csproj
COPY src/ src/
RUN dotnet publish src/Company.Product.Component.App/Company.Product.Component.App.csproj -c Release --no-restore -o /out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS run-env
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Company.Product.Component.App.dll"]
```

The `COPY src/ src/` layer in the sources-env is invalidated by source changes, but cache invalidation works separately for each stage. As the files copied over to the build-env are the same across builds, the `COPY --from=projects-env` cache is not invalidated, so the `RUN dotnet restore` layer is taken from the cache, too.

I suspect there are other solutions using the [BuildKit mounts](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/syntax.md) (`RUN --mount=...`), but I haven't tested any.

Comment: Thanks, @VonC. :-) I edited in another solution that works with BuildKit too. Also had a look at the BuildKit mounts and they may lead to even simpler solutions (working only with BuildKit, though). Learned a ton about Docker today.

Comment: Well done. I have referenced your question in my answer, for more visibility.

Comment: How does the Buildkit solution work? Wouldn't the projects-env section execute on any change on the source code and everything after as well?

Comment: @JuanDelaCruz, the explanation is just below the code of the solution. Cache invalidation works for each stage separately. projects-env executes on any change, but the resulting projects-env image will be the same most of the time. build-env will miss the cache of its COPY layer only if the files in projects-env changed.

Comment: I read everything till that last part...thanks! I looked at the docs but didn't find any mention of cache invalidation being independent on each stage.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the alternative way to solve the problem.

First, copy the **.sln** and **.csproj** files (depends on the solution folder structure)

```
COPY *.sln ./
COPY **/*.csproj ./
COPY **/**/**/*.csproj ./
```

After that run the following script:

```
RUN dotnet sln list | grep ".csproj" \
    | while read -r line; do \ 
    mkdir -p $(dirname $line); \
    mv $(basename $line) $(dirname $line); \
    done;
```

The script simply moves **.csproj** files to the same locations they are in the host filesystem.

Comment: This works without BuildKit, but the wildcards do not work when BuildKit is enabled. But using the project paths from the solution file instead of based on a convention is a nice idea. I suspect the paths need some fixing of backslashes in the script, though, which your script does not do.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more modern version that works with buildkit and doesn't depend on folder structures and filenames being identical, or the output of `dotnet sln list`. It does depend on the `find` command being available in your base image, but for anything with dotnet SDK installed, that should be no issue.

```
RUN --mount=type=bind,target=/docker-context \
    cd /docker-context/; \
    find ./ -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 4 \( -name "*.sln" -o -name "*.csproj" -o -iname "nuget.config" \) -exec cp --parents "{}" / \;
```

A breakdown of what this does:

1. `RUN`: obviously runs a command.
2. `--mount=type=bind,target=/docker-context`: mounts the current build directory (ie. on the machine running the build) into the Docker container at `/docker-context`.
3. `cd /docker-context/`: changes to that mount directory inside your docker container.
4. `find ./ -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 4` search inside that directory (with a min/max subdirectory depth, adjust to your own requirements)
5. `\( -name "*.sln" -o -name "*.csproj" -o -iname "nuget.config" \)`: Tells the `find` command to match anything like `*.sln` or `*.csproj` or `nuget.config` (Using `-iname` for case insensitive matching since the casing of `NuGet.config` often differs).
   I specifically like to include the sln and nuget files because they can have impact on the package restore and build later, YMMV.
6. `-exec cp --parents "{}" /` copy item and all its parents (ie. keep structure) to `/`, where `/` is the current working dir in your docker environment.

This one-liner is enough to copy all your projects using wildcard, while preserving the directory structure.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66137816/928483) by [@Joost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171436/joost) here. Thanks!